# Ловлю ошибку при вводе пустого символа боту VK(VK.API)

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, api, long-poll

Создаю бота для сообщества вконтакте, бот просто должен выводить тоже сообщение что и пользователь, обратно пользователю,проблема возникла при вводе пользователем пустого символа,программа крашится,ошибка связана со словарём,я не сильно в этом шарю,самое интересное что крашит не всегда,а от определенного пользователя, возможно мы вводим разный код для пустого символа.К коду не придирайтесь,я в основном писал по урокам и гуглил некоторые участки кода,опять же палкой не бейте

```
public static void LongPoll()
        {
            string token = File.ReadAllText("C:\\Users\\ярослав\\source\\repos\\Bot_\\token.txt");

            VkApi vk = new VkApi();

            var webClient = new WebClient() { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 };

            vk.Authorize(new ApiAuthParams()
            {
                ApplicationId = 1,
                AccessToken = token,                     
                Settings = Settings.All
            }) ;
            Console.WriteLine($"Авторизация: {vk.IsAuthorized}");// false - Авторизация не прошла 
            var param = new VkParameters() { };
            param.Add<string>("group_id", "1");// id Группы вк
            param.Add<string>("access_token", token);

            //vk.Groups.GetMembers()
            dynamic responseLongPoll = JObject.Parse(vk.Call("groups.getLongPollServer", param).RawJson);

            string json = String.Empty;
            string url = string.Empty;

            while (true)// Инфа о событиях сообщества
            {
                   Random random = new Random();
                   int i = random.Next(0,4);
                   string AnswerMessage = Word[i];

                url = string.Format("{0}?act=a_check&key={1}&ts={2}&wait=25",
                    responseLongPoll.response.server.ToString(),
                    responseLongPoll.response.key.ToString(),
                    
                    json != String.Empty ? JObject.Parse(json)["ts"].ToString() : responseLongPoll.response.ts.ToString());
                    json = webClient.DownloadString(url);

                

                var col = JObject.Parse(json)["updates"].ToList();

                foreach(var item in col)
                {
                    if (item["type"].ToString() == "message_new")
                    {
                        string msg = item["object"]["message"]["text"].ToString();
                        int IdPers = Convert.ToInt32(item["object"]["message"]["from_id"]);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Пришло новое сообщение: {msg} От {IdPers}");
                        vk.Messages.Send(new VkNet.Model.RequestParams.MessagesSendParams
                        {
                            RandomId = 0, 
                            UserId = IdPers,
                            Message = $"{msg}"
                           
                        });
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: ошибка,в консоль выводится то,что написал пользователь]

Comment: ну, видимо, просто библиотека так сделана, что кидает вам исключение при попытке пустой строки, она не позволит вам это сделать

Comment: текст исключения вставь текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: @KuzCode я ранее написал что исключения выбрасывает не всегда, я могу отправить пустую строку разными кодами по типу &#4448; , но на некоторые выбрасывает исключение

Comment: _&#4448;_ - это НЕ пустая строка